# MySQL ORDER BY with coefficient?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `story` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rating_1_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_2_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_3_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_4_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_5_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `favorite_nb` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

As you can see, I store the number of times a one star (rating_1_nb), two stars (rating_2_nb)... ratings have been posted on a particular story. What I want to create is a ranking of the best stories and of the worst depending on the ratings these stories got.

I would like to create an SQL query which automatically orders the stories according to their ratings. So my idea was to have a coefficient for every ratings columns so I could easily make a calculation but I'm not sure if it's a good idea, in terms of performance. Do you have a suggestion to give in order to create this particular MySQL query ?

Comment: if you're going to do this order by often, store the total rating as a float, and update it everytime you update one of the rating_X_nb.

Comment: @rlanvin yes, that's also an idea I thought about! Will see if better solutions are given but this could be one ;-)

Comment: there is no "better" solutions in terms of performance. The other solution is to order by (rating_1_nb + 2*rating_2_nb + 3*rating_3_nb + 4*rating_4_nb + 5*rating_5_nb) / (rating_1_nb + rating_2_nb+ rating_3_nb + rating_4_nb + rating_5_nb), which will be slower because calculated each time.

Answer (score 0):

For me this will make more sense, ratings with coefficient

```
SELECT *, ( rating_1_nb*1 + rating_2_nb*2 + rating_3_nb*3 + rating_4_nb*4 + rating_5_nb*5) as ratings FROM story order by ratings
```

This will be efficient and effective too.

Hope it helps you too

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

First: Don't use a coefficient, just order by the ratings. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY rating_5_nb DESC, rating_4_nb DESC,
rating_3_nb DESC, rating_2_nb DESC, rating_1_nb DESC
```

This works like the ratings in the Olympic Games, where gold medals come first, then silver and so on. So every 5-star rating is more important than any number of 4-star ratings.

Second: Do some fancy calculations.

```
SELECT (rating_1_nb * c_1 +  rating_2_nb * c_2 + rating_3_nb * c_3 +
rating_4_nb * 4_2 + rating_5 * c_5) AS rating FROM ratings ORDER BY rating
```

You shouldn't worry about performance. SQL queries are heavily optimized by your DBMS. As long as you do not need a lot of joins you do not have to think a lot about your query.